# Customizing ref of reaction environment

Tags: hyperref, environments, chemmacros

I am using the reaction environment from the chemmacros package to typeset a few, simple chemical reactions.

I would like to customize the way I am referencing to my reaction. Ideally, the whole reference name (and hence hyperlink) would be "Reaction {#1}" (yes, with the curly brackets, to be consistent with the equation tag).

I cannot use the cleveref package, as it has weird interactions with the rest of my document, I would rather stick with the \ref and \autoref commands. Here is my MWE (please note that I am actually using a memoir class document, if it changes anything):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\chemsetup{modules = all}
\begin{document}
Reaction \autoref{rxn:water} is good.
\begin{reaction}
H3O+ + HO- = 2 H2O "\label{rxn:water}"
\end{reaction}
\\
Reaction \ref{rxn:water} is just water...
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can modify how `hyperref` chooses the string to write in the `aux` file by testing whether `\theHequation` begins with `R`, which is how `chemmacros` modifies it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\chemsetup{modules=all,greek=textgreek}

\makeatletter % patchcmd from etoolbox, loaded by chemmacros
\patchcmd{\hyper@makecurrent}
 {\edef\Hy@param{#1}}
 {\xHy@param@def{#1}}
 {}{}
\def\xHy@param@def#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \edef\Hy@param{\if R\@tempa reaction\else#1\fi}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\reactionautorefname{Reaction}

\begin{document}

\autoref{rxn:water} is good.
\begin{reaction}
H3O+ + HO- = 2 H2O "\label{rxn:water}"
\end{reaction}
Reaction \ref{rxn:water} is just water...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can adapt `\ref{...}` to be used with chemical reactions only:

```
\newcommand{\rxnref}[1]{Reaction~\{\#\ref{#1}\}}
```

However, I cannot think of a good solution for `\autoref{...}`. Normally you would want to adjust the prefix with something like `\def\reactionautorefname{Reaction}`, but to my knowledge there is no `\reactionautorefname{...}` to begin with. `chemmacros`'s `reaction` environment is a wrapper for `amsmath`'s `align` environment, hence you would need to use `\def\equationautorefname{Reaction}`, but in this case both reactions and math equations receive "Reaction" prefix, which make little sense. Therefore the best solution is probably to use `rxnref{...}` only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{modules = all}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\rxnref}[1]{Reaction~\{\#\ref{#1}\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    H3O+ + HO- = 2 H2O "\label{rxn:water}"
\end{reaction}

\rxnref{rxn:water} is just water...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With an up to date `chemmacros` (v6.1 2022/02/13) this works out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\autoref{rxn:water} is good.
\begin{reaction}
  H3O+ + HO- == 2 H2O \label{rxn:water}
\end{reaction}
Reaction \ref{rxn:water} is just water...

\end{document}
```

[image]